# Unable to rewrite url in Nginx to login as admin on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nginx, docker-compose

I'm running Wordpress containerized in docker-compose, but for some reason I can't enter http://localhost/wp-admin to login to the dashboard. I get a 404 error from nginx.

This url does work instead: http://localhost/wp/wp-login.php

So I'm trying to rewrite this in nginx, but I get the same 404 response:

```
    rewrite ^wp-admin$ wp/wp-login.php last;
```

Why isn't this working?

Full conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/html/web;

    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    # add url to login as admin
    rewrite ^wp-admin$ wp/wp-login.php last;

    # fix slash
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you wouldn't point the server block root to `/var/www/html/web/wp`?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Assuming you have a wp-login.php inside /var/www/html/web/wp

```
  location = /wp-admin {
        rewrite ^/wp-admin?$ /wp/wp-login.php break;
  }
```

my guess is you're trying to change the WP admin location, this will most likely break the WordPress site. if so Don't.